# Why is function reference still unresolved when link library was found?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, linker, g++

I am trying to implement my own thumbnail provider by following [Microsoft's thumbnail provider code sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/appshellintegration/RecipeThumbnailProvider). The code has been coming together nicely, but now I needed to figure out a way to compile (on Windows). [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) appears to be a popular option.

```
g++ -shared -o GrmgThumbnailProvider.dll -lshlwapi -lgdi32 Dll.cpp GrmgThumbnailProvider.cpp
```

This causes errors:

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Zyl\AppData\Local\Temp\cc5HnXOH.o:Dll.cpp:(.text$_ZN13CClassFactory14QueryInterfaceERK5_GUIDPPv[_ZN13CClassFactory14QueryInterfaceERK5_GUIDPPv]+0x31): undefined reference to `QISearch'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Zyl\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXzQLhd.o:GrmgThumbnailProvider.cpp:(.text+0x36f): undefined reference to `__imp_CreateDIBSection'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Zyl\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXzQLhd.o:GrmgThumbnailProvider.cpp:(.text$_ZN18CGrmgThumbProvider14QueryInterfaceERK5_GUIDPPv[_ZN18CGrmgThumbProvider14QueryInterfaceERK5_GUIDPPv]+0x31): undefined reference to `QISearch'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The libraries are definitely found: g++ complains if I change the library names in the `-l` argument to some nonsense. How is it these references cannot be resolved despite the required libraries being both present and found?

- [QISearch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-qisearch)
- [CreateDIBSection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createdibsection)

Comment: you  need to put your libraries after your cpp files

Comment: The most popular option to compile on Windows is probably Visual Studio (there's a free community edition available). It's certainly the most simple option. Lots of problems with GCC and MSYS with out-of-date headers, etc.